# Does anyone know the thread size (pitch and lead) of the Anet A8's lead screw?

Tags: prusa-i3, z-axis, hardware, lead-screw, anet-a8

I bought a new printer, and unfortunately the left nut for the lead screw isn't tapped.

Does anyone know the thread size, w.r.t. both pitch and lead, of the lead screws?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the Anet A8, I confirm the threads are Tr8x8(p2). This is explained as "Tr" for trapezoidal thread followed by the nominal diameter in mm. The digits after the "x" denotes the lead of the screw (how much does the nut advance per revolution). The value between the brackets "p2" denotes the pitch. This means that the screw has 8 (lead) / 2 (pitch) = 4 starts.

More information on threads is found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_thread_form).

Answer (score 2):

I don't own the printer, but the [intertubes](https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32827343801.html) identify it as a "TR8X8 T" (8mm diameter / 8mm offset per revolution).

Answer (score 0):

The pitch no matter the screw is the distance between the threads. The lead can be different based on a one or two start threads.

Comment: Hi Darron, and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it *is* lacking detail, and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion, unfortunately. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions, in particular [answer], and take the [tour] for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)

Comment: ... or even four start threads...